# NSTouchbar Exception when exiting compiled python code

Tags: python, wxpython, pyinstaller

I have written a Gui in python using wx.Python, and compiled it using Pyinstaller.  My code runs fine in Pycharm, but the compiled version throws the error below when I click away from the gui.  I've google this one with no luck, any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Exception:

```
2019-02-04 09:59:56.023 PCL601XCE_app[64617:9836366] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '[NSTouchBar(<NSTouchBar: 0x7fab42155940 configuration='<NSTouchBarCustomizableConfiguration: 0x7fab4213eb50 identifier='(null)'>' delegate='0x7fab406d80c0'>) itemIdentifiers] was mutated while items array was being built'
```

Comment: It's important to share the code of where the error is happening, when the button is pressed, so people can see what could be wrong.

Comment: @George, Ya I realize that but this is a fairly large piece of code and since this error only happens in the compiled version, I am not sure which portion of the project is causing the issue.  Since I am not using the touchbar in my code, this seemed a bit more generic than a specific line of code.  Perhaps I need to dig a bit more